# Send multiple rows to one email

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please, i have a script that send email to customers. The problem with the script is that it sends multiple mails but all i want is for it to send one mail containing details of multiple rows. i.e all the bill details should be in a table.

below is my script

Thanks

```
$bill_status = "OVERDUE";
$st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(), due_date) AS days_diff 
FROM bills LEFT JOIN login_details ON bills.user_id = login_details.user_id
WHERE bills.bill_status = '$bill_status'");
$st->execute();
$row_sent = $st->rowCount();

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;  // Enable verbose     debug output

$mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'localhost';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;    // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mails@mail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'pasword';                 // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Port = 465;                   // TCP port to connect to
$mail->From = 'no_reply@noreply.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Coy Name';

$mail->WordWrap = 587;        // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("../img/logo.png", "logo");
$mail->isHTML(true);      // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Notice';
while($rows = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$username = $rows['username'];

$message= "
<div class='messages'>
<h3><img src='cid:my_logo'> </h3>
<br>
<div style='font-size:15px;'>Email Notification on Bill Due for Payment      </h4>
<p>Dear: Customer</p>
<p>
The following bills are due for payment:
</p>
<table width='80%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr style='font-weight:bold;'>
<td>Trans Ref</td>
            <td>Due Date</td>
            <td>Days Overdue</td>
            <td>Service Provider</td>
            <td>Service Type</td>
            <td>Amount Paid</td>
            <td>Bill Status</td>
            <td>Recurring</td>
  </tr>

 <h3>Yours<br>
Coy Name</h3>
";    

$message .= "        <tr>";
$message .= "            <td>".$rows['trans_ref']."</td>";
$message .= "            <td>".$rows['due_date']."</td>";
$message .= "            <td>".$rows['days_diff']."</td>";
$message .= "            <td>".$rows['service_provider']."</td>";
$message .= "            <td>".$rows['service_type']."</td>";
$message .= "            <td>".$rows['amount_paid']."</td>";
$message .= "            <td>".$rows['bill_status']."</td>";
$message .= "            <td>".$rows['recurring']."</td>";
$message .= "        </tr>";

$mail->addAddress($username);     // Add a recipient
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->send();
$mail->ClearAddresses();

}
```

Comment: you put the mail send function inside a loop... start with this fact.

Comment: and replace this with placeholder `WHERE bills.bill_status = '$bill_status'");`

Comment: First create the $message header  then loop all rows `while($rows = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$username = $rows['username']; $message .= "<tr>yourcode</tr>"; }`  after that do the `$mail->addAddress($username);` stuff.   Does the SQL only load data for one `username`?

Comment: the problem is that it sends the whole bills to all the users instead of sending each user their own bill(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop should only be around the

```
$message .= "        <tr>";
....
$message .= "        </tr>";
```

statements. Otherwise all other statements are executed multiple times, too.

Comment: but i dont know why it wont send on cron but only works manually?

Comment: Sorry. Didnt work. It sends to all the email address in the database still